# use post and or get to submit post on a page and view in another. similar to a blog

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, blogs

I am a little frustrated, but trying to work through this in my free time.  What I want is to create a blog page for my daughter and I am a bit of a beginner myself when it comes to web design, although I do know css and html like the back of my hand.  My question is with php and or mySQL  what I want is to have my daughter write her blog/story (she is 9) on one generic page for submitting text that I've written to a spot on her page on our family website, still in the making.  So I have learned how to post something, but not to a target space on a specific page.  I assume that you use an anchor tag on her page rose.html and getelmentbyID or post?  I'm now confused.  I can look up the connection sequence for php if someone doesn't want to explain all that to me, but bear with me, while I have some experience with php and mysql I am still a little green behind the ears.  Anything would help.

Comment: Like are you trying to for example post a dynamic p text in a specific div?

Comment: Here are 2 cents I have to offer, it may save you some programming, but it may not be what you are after either.  You could create a private/protected WordPress site for her (or any other blogging platform) where she makes posts.  On your family site, use a PHP RSS reader to fetch the posts from her blog and output them where you want on the family site.  This should be doable fairly easily and with minimal custom code.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be MUCH better off using something like WordPress - if you know HTML/CSS well you can customize it to be very useful to you.

It's dead simple to install and theirs a million guides out their for you to use.

http://wordpress.org/

Give it a shot, it'll make you life a lot easier.

Theming WordPress:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/building-custom-wordpress-theme

Answer (score 1):

Say your dynamically posting a p message to a div from submitting words in a text box named "entry". You would just insert the php in the middle of the div where you want to see it. For example

```
<div>
<!--PHP HERE-->
<?php
    $post = $_POST['entry'];
     echo '<p>'.$post.'</p>';
?>
<!--END PHP-->
</div>
<!--Area you enter message to post-->
<form method="post" action="<!--PUT NAME OF FILE HERE-->">
<textarea name="entry" cols="40" rows="5">
Enter your comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```